# jQuery unbind not working as i expected

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery

```
$('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var reason = $('.agree_reason:visible');
    var reason_text = $('.agree_reason:visible textarea');
    if(reason.length == 0){
        $('.agree').show();
    }else{
        if(reason_text.val() == ''){
            $('.agree').show();
            $('#application_agree').css('border', '1px solid #CC0000');
            $('.agree_validation_message').show();
        }else{
            $('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]').unbind();
            $('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]').click();
        }
    }
});
```

and all is great up until the unbind....what i need it to do is remove this handler and do the normal click event but its freezing up my browser because its in a infinite loop i guess....i ever tried the jQuery die fundtion and also no luck...any ideas

Comment: @Sneakyness you mean `return true;` I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass the event type to `unbind`

```
$('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]').unbind("click");
```

Also, based on PeeHaa's comment, `application_submit` is the element id, and since elements in the dom are unique (or at least better be), you can simplify this to

```
$('#application_submit').unbind("click");
```

You're almost always better off selecting by a simple id like this, since jQuery can defer to the native `document.getElementById` under the covers.

Another improvement would be:

```
var reason = $('.agree_reason:visible');
var reason_text = $('textarea', reason); // it is faster to let jQuery search in context
```

Comment: Also, I *think* you can chain these calls like any other: `$('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]').unbind("click").click();`

Comment: While we are improving the code: `$('input#application_submit')` is faster than `$('input#application_submit.bigbutton[value=Agree]')`. The latter isn't needed because you are already doing a selector based on an `id` which is unique.